# How to know which is the default script shell in Centos?

Tags: shell, centos, dash

I'm using Centos 6 and after reading about different shells and dash implementasion as sh replacement in Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora, made up my mind to replace sh with dash as the script shell in Centos.

I have no idea how to see if this is already done, because I have both sh and dash in my system, so how do I know which is my default script shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can determine your default shell with the following command:

```
grep -- "$LOGNAME" /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{print $7}'
```

In my machine, `sh` is a link to `dash`, try:

```
ls -l "$(which sh)"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, in my machine sh is a link to bash.`lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 mar  9 22:42 /bin/sh -> bash`

Answer (score 3):

The "script shell" is *not* the login shell. It is whatever is running as `/bin/sh`. Note that many Bourne shell derivatives (i.e., `sh`s like bash and dash, and probably also the Korn shell lookalikes) behave differently when called as `sh`

Comment: Good advice; I don't think `dash` has a life outside of serving as `sh`, so its behavior probably _doesn't_ change when invoked as `sh` (do tell me if you know that it does).

Answer (score 0):

On Centos (and ever in other linuxes & unices) you can know what is the shell you are using doing this commands:

```
$ id
uid=501(john1) gid=1000(groupname1) ....
```

that tell you that you are using user `john1` and then:

```
$ grep john1 /etc/passwd
john1:x:501:1000:john1,,,:/home/john1:/bin/bash
```

the last string afther `/` tell you what is your login shell (in this example is `/bin/bash')

To change your login shell you can edit (as user `root`) this string into `passwd` but be carefull to do not change anythig else.

If you have a Graphical Interface installed (like GNOME  or KDE) there are other graphical tools to change this settings.

Comment: If you want to change your shell, use chsh.

Comment: I wasn't asking for my user shell, but rather the script shell that executes daemons. The first answer made it.

Comment: Actualy my answer and the other one are exactly the same (the clever " |awk ... " bit does extract the same string I mention). I agree that user shell and 'daemons' shell are very different things. It's the shebang line of every script in /etc/init.d that rules. In Centos it is usually #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash (and /bin/sh is usually a link to /bin/bash). I strongly advise against to mess up with this shebangs nor with this link or very bad things will follow.

Comment: the point here is that Centos startup scripts are written specifically for Bash (#!/bin/bash) or for a particular mode of bash that mimic "historical versions of sh" (#!/bin/sh). If you try to change the shell (changing the link at /bin/sh) you broke things. In recent Debian/Ubunt the scripts (and the shell) use dash and ever here is unwise to force another shell for the same reasons.

Comment: If the centos scripts are made for bash that mimics sh, and dash also does this, in theory there would be no breaks. But I don't know and if I don't try I will truly never know.

Comment: Yeap, you've been right, the system broke down. Already fixed.

Answer (score -1):

the best way to change it is to use usermod in Centos

```
usermod -s /bin/bash username
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question